# Adding two queries in SQL function

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to create a function like the below, essentially I need to query for two money values and then add them together and return the result. Is that possible?

Thanks

```
CREATE function [dbo].[fn_manualpricing2-NEW](@type varchar(50),@capid int,@milespa int, @maintained bit, @term int, @product varchar(50), @funder varchar(50))
returns money
as
BEGIN

RETURN (
SELECT TOP 1 price FROM tblPricing WHERE [type]=@type AND term=@term AND milespa=@milespa AND capid=@capid AND maintained=@maintained AND source=@funder and product=@product ORDER BY price
+
SELECT TOP 1 addonpricevalue FROM [dbWebsiteLO3-PRICING].[dbo].[AddonPrices] WHERE VehicleType=1 AND term=@term AND miles=@milespa AND source=@funder
)
END

GO
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough to add parenthesis around the selects themselves (SELECT ..) + (SELECT ...) ?

Comment: Thanks Allan, that did it! Silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this..

```
CREATE function [dbo].[fn_manualpricing2-NEW](@type varchar(50),@capid int,@milespa int, @maintained bit, @term int, @product varchar(50), @funder varchar(50))
returns money
as
BEGIN

DECLARE @variable money
SET @variable = (SELECT TOP 1 price FROM tblPricing WHERE [type]=@type AND term=@term AND milespa=@milespa AND capid=@capid AND maintained=@maintained AND source=@funder and product=@product ORDER BY price)
+
(SELECT TOP 1 addonpricevalue FROM [dbWebsiteLO3-PRICING].[dbo].[AddonPrices] WHERE VehicleType=1 AND term=@term AND miles=@milespa AND source=@funder)

return @variable 

END

GO
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with less code, but this gives you the general idea:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ufn_AddTwoValues()
RETURNS Money
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
-- place the body of the function here
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ValOne money;
    DECLARE @ValTwo money;
    DECLARE @Result money;

    SET @ValOne = (SELECT 1);
    SET @ValTwo = (SELECT 2);

    SET @Result = @ValOne + @ValTwo;

    RETURN @Result;
END
GO

select dbo.ufn_AddTwoValues()
```